# VB.NET TableAdapter insert query not saving to database

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I created an `INSERT` query to my `UsersDataSet`. (right-click -> new query -> sql -> insert). After calling `UsersTableAdapter.InsertUser(user,pass,firstname,lastname)`, I notice the query executes successfully but the data is not saved to the database. Why is this happening?

PS: I have done this before and it do saves.

Comment: weird behavior.....may show more code please.

Comment: There is no more code :(  It's all done by the "Add new DataSource" wizard, and the "Add Query" wizard. I'm just calling the function above and it doesn't saves it.

Comment: curious....have you tried to put it into a try catch ?????take a try and let me know if is show error.

Answer (score 1):

This is super stupid, the issue was that since I copied the MS Access file, everytime I rebuilt the project, the database file was also overwritten, along with the previous build files, with the blank database file I set as the datasource

Comment: So how did you fix it as I have the same problem and even after I close the application, then open the database, my new records are not there?
Also, Note that if I add a new record using the query builder and execute then the data is saved and kept there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call TableAdapter.Update() to persist the changes back to the database. You are creating a row in the datatable, but not pushing your changes to the data source.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx